# PHP Caching - keeping database writes in sync with read cache

Tags: php, caching

Scenario: I have an ajax autocomplete lookup that grabs data from a memory cache. The autocomplete checks for an expired cache and reloads every minute. Works fine.

I'm wondering what the best strategy is for syncing the writes with the cache.

Should I update the cache every time a user writes to the db so that the cache has the latest data or simply live with the fact that the cache is a little old. The cache data is not super time critical -- it's a list of post tags.

Updating the cache on every write seems to make the cache a little redundant, but not absolutely so.

I appreciate that this is activity-dependent.

How do others deal with this?

Comment: If it's not dead critical, you should be fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should either update the cache or invalidate it.  One of my biggest pet peeves with Google Contacts is that updates to contacts take **forever** to propagate to Gmail and Google Voice's fancy autocomplete gizmometers.  Please, for the love of all that is holy and righteous, do not subject your users to that!

Comment: Yeah, I get that. My cache expires every minute so that's not a big issue. But I also think that the writes to the db should fire a cache update. My theory is that on any site that allows user tagging like SO, the ratio of reads to writes is extremely high.